# How to get class of an object?

Tags: python

I need to get the exact class of an object to raise TypeError and print it on to the console.

```
def diff(a,b):
  retset = []
  if not isinstance(a,set) or not isinstance(b,set):
      raise TypeError("Unsupported operand type(s) for -: '{}' and        '{}'".format(type(a),type(b)))
  else:
      for item in a:
          if not item in b:
              retset.append(item)
   return set(retset)
```

if I pass args that are not sets, for example, 1 set and 1 list, this outputs
    Unsupported operand type(s) for -: class 'set' and class 'list'

whereas I want the output as
    unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'set' and 'list'

Is there a specific built-in functions like type()?

Comment: `type(obj).__name__`

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the word `class` from the output of `type(e)`?

Comment: Thanks @meowgoesthedog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__class__` attribute to get the actual class of the object, and from that you can get the `__name__` attribute.

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo:
    pass
foo = Foo()
```

With the above, `print(foo.__class__.__name__)` will yield `Foo`

Answer (score 1):

Use `type(obj).__name__`:

```
x = object()
print(type(x).__name__)
```

Using `type(obj)` returns the type of the object. All types have the `__name__` attribute, which is a string representing the object's name.

Note: using `str(type(obj))` will return something you don't expect:

```
"<class 'object'>"
```